# iPad Pages: replacing the wood effect theme

Tags: ipad, pages

Is there any way to replace the brown wood-effect toolbars used by Pages on the iPad with something more neutral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is jailbroken, I assume you can modify files within an app's bundle? I haven't jailbroken my device, so I'm not sure exactly how this works. However, if you have:

Within the Pages bundle, there are images called `TP_RulerBackground.png` and `TP_toolbar_top_bg_norm.png`. If you replace these files with something else, it'll change the toolbars/rulers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not jailbroken, and in fact it's not my device - it's a family member who I'd have a hard time explaining the concept to. But otherwise that would work.

Comment: There's really no conceivable other way you would be able to do it. Unless Pages offered a preference for changing the toolbars (which they don't), you'd have to change them yourself, and to do that you'd have to jailbreak.